# If I require a file in application.rb does this make it available throughout the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

**Application.rb:**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'parse-ruby-client'

Parse.init :application_id => "<APP_ID>",
           :api_key        => "<API_KEY>"


# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module GarmentsROR
  class Application < Rails::Application

  end
end
```

My gem parse-ruby-client doesn't seem to allow my rails app to connect to my parse.com account. I have a feeling I've put Parse.init in the wrong place.

The instructions weren't very clear. It assumes I should know where they go.

Would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was forgetting to remove the symbols `<` and `>` out of the APP ID and API KEY. Doing this solved all my issues.

Answer (score 1):

You should create an initializer in config/initializers/parse_ruby_client.rb with:

```
Parse.init :application_id => "<APP_ID>",
           :api_key        => "<API_KEY>"
```

Comment: Done, so then how does the gem know how to communicate with this file? Will it just work?

Comment: It depends what init method does! If it sets the data, than initializers are the right place to do that, because theese files are loaded only once when server is started!